# How do I get loading the new nuget package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlSever v8.0.0 to work under ,net 8

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I keep getting the message[Micsoft.Win32.SystemEvents doesn't support net 8 windows]
See the image below.

[image]

I am trying to start a new wpf desktop project with the latest services.

Am I doing something wrong or has Microsoft stuffed up?

Tried loading `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer v8.0.0` and other versions but get the same message.

Comment: I think the answer is pretty clear here. You need to change your target framework. Take a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-multi-targeting-overview?view=vs-2022

Comment: Please explain the precise steps we need to follow to see the error you are. Your question is a bit vague and open to interpretation.

Comment: I have tried that it still comes up with the same message. I changed it to to .net 6.

Comment: I set up a new project WPF. with .net 8 as per standard. with nothing added before trying loading the microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer and got the message. Same for ,net 6.

Comment: Here is a video recording of my actions. OOps can't add a video.

Comment: Post the content of the `.csproj` file